# Is 'Fill it up, will you?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, american-english, tag-questions

I seem to recall to have heard this form of making a request in an american series:

> Fill it up [referring to a drink], *will you*?

Is it grammatically and idiomatically correct? At first it sounded a bit awkward because I would usually phrase it this say:

> Will you fill it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [this site](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/decl.htm) which appears very legit, this is called an "Imperative sentence", and that form is valid:

> Tag questions are sometimes added to the end of imperatives:
>
> *Leave your coat in the hall, will you?*
>             *Write soon, won't you?*